# Masstransit Dequeue without consumer

Tags: c#, masstransit

We are attempting to replace an old Messaging library with MassTransit and running into a blockade.

We have a requirement for our applications to connect to a queue and pull off a single message at a time on a schedule.

Is this possible in MassTransit?   It seems all of the documentation I have found shows setting up the ReceiveEndpoint with a Consumer.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  Looks like we might be rewriting some logic!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this answered in here, I am repeating Chris Pattersons comment above.  It is not possible.